# GridView Command Button Unable to Delete

Tags: c#, events, gridview

I added a Delete Command button to my GridView but whenever i chick the button i get an error which is:

- [HttpException (0x80004005): The GridView 'GridView1' fired event RowDeleting which wasn't         handled.]
- System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.OnRowDeleting(GridViewDeleteEventArgs e) +1463321

but i dont know whats the event that i should use and what to delete and edit, here is my code:

```
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
                 <ItemTemplate>
                   <asp:Button ID="lkDelte" runat="server" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')"
                                CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument='<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>'></asp:Button>
                   </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>






protected void gdCourse_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
    {
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

        GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[index];

        string con_str = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(con_str);

        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("dbo.delete_documents", con);
        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlParameter pDocument_ID = new SqlParameter("@document_id", row);

        com.Parameters.Add(pDocument_ID);

        con.Open();
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

    }
    else
    {
        Label2.Text = "Unable to delete";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong with your code but you forgot to handle the `RowDeleting` event of your grid view.

You need to handle the gridview `RowDeleting` method:

`protected void gvLineItems_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)`

In this case you can just rebind in this method or leave the method empty but add it's signature so the event can fire correctly.

Add this to your program:

```
protected void NameOfYourGridView_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
 {
  //bind your grid view here...
 }
```

Comment: sorry but you mean that i should delete 
`protected void gdCourse_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)` 

and add

 
`protected void gvLineItems_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)`   

including the code inside ???

Comment: No you should NOT delete anything, you need RowCommand to fire for the type of action, which in your case is "delete".  You need both RowCommand and RowDeleting.  RowCommand is called for the delete but you need to handle the RowDeleting for the deleted row.  This can be an empty function but the compiler needs the signature so just add the signature.

Comment: great the error isnt showing now but the problem is that its not deleting the record

should i do something with <asp:> tags,,,, i mean to specify which event 

i mean should i add OnRowCommand = ""  OnRowDeleting = "" in the GridView tag

Comment: You have to rebind your grid that is why, show your event that you added the RowDeleting event.  You have to rebind the grid, in addition, `Dataset ds = GetYourData(); myGrid.DataSource=ds; myGrid.DataBind();` this should all be inside of rowdeleting event.

Comment: im new to ASP.NET AND C#. i`m sorry but i really cant understand wht u mean by rebind Could u or anyone show me with code. i just need help

Comment: @user1744446 - How do you first load your gridview?  Whatever method you use to load the gridview you need to reload it after you perform the deletion.  There is not much wrong with your code, you just need to handle the rowdeleting event and rebind the grid.  To rebind the grid you must refill it (in addition, grab your data and store it in a datatable, dataset, or a reader.  Then set the object's datasource propety to your datatable / dataset / reader, then call .DataBind()).